# I have a factor columns in R. I am trying to delete it but I keep getting errors messages. How do I delete a factor column in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, null

My data frame ***df*** has has a factor column. The column is just filled with "yes" and "no" values. I used the following formula:

*** df$column <- NULL***

However I get the following messages;

**Warning message:
In Ops.factor(df$Embarked, NULL) : ‘<’ not meaningful for factors**

**&**

**logical(0)**

Can someone advise what formula to use instead of the one I used please?

Comment: How about `df <- df[,-which(names(df) == "column")]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)
df <- select(df, -column)
```

Answer (score 0):

It should work.

```r
df <-
    data.frame(fac = factor(sample(
        c("yes", "no"), size = 10, replace = TRUE
    )), ind = 1:10)
df$fac <- NULL
# column is removed
```

Check if `NULL` is valid, not being overwritten by something else.